# Bash Script Problems

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, scripting

I'm working on a script... I don't know what is wrong with it...

```
!#/bin/bash
while="true"
while ($while == "true") do
clear
echo "What game would you like to play?"
echo "1. Tetris (bastet)"
read number -P "Enter Number:"
if ( $number == "1" ) then
bastet
clear
read again -P "Would you like to play another game? [y/n]:"
if ($again == "n") then
exit
fi
fi
done
```

this is my output (that loops):

```
What game would you like to play?
1. Tetris (bastet)
```

without the prompt from the read command

Comment: I stopped counting after 3 lines: `#!` not `!#`; using reserved word `while` as a variable; `(`, `)` make a subshell not a test construct

Comment: You could start by correcting errors shown by pasting your script in [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where good code tabular format makes a difference in seeing your problems and mistakes.  The problem is that your *if statement* never allows the script to jump out of the loop.  Also you're missing some echos and all the other stuff that steeldriver and user4556274 indicated.

I didn't really RE-CODE what you wrote, so you can still have a feel for where you went wrong.

See my revision:

```
#!/bin/bash

flag="true"
while [ $flag == "true" ]; do
        clear
        echo "What game would you like to play?"
        echo "1. Tetris (bastet)"
        read number -P "Enter Number:"

        if [ $number -eq "1" ]; then
                bastet
        fi

        clear
        echo "Would you like to play another game? [y/n]:"
        read again -P

        if [ $again -eq "n" ]; then
                exit 1
        fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks alot, the script works as should. I need to refresh my bash script knowledge...feel like a bit of an idiot.

Comment: @Edward Brown "try read -p "Enter Number:" number instead" fixed the prompt issue

Answer (score 0):

There are a few other things wrong with your script, but to answer your specific question about read, the syntax is wrong in a few ways:

try `read -p "Enter Number:" number` instead

[Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) is a useful page regarding **read**